# Retrieve Json value from laravel database

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have table where has column (named `order_data`) which saves data as Json, now I want to retrieve data out of that column but all I get is column data itself as sample below

```
"{\"29\":{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"effewf\",\"price\":24524,\"quantity\":1,\"attributes\":[],\"conditions\":[]}}"
```

[image: screenshot]

**My question is:**

> How do I get my data such as `Product->title` out of that json column
>   which is `effewf` in my sample code, or prices etc.

here is my current function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('admin.orders.index', compact('orders'));
    }
```

PS: I cleaned my function because all my ways I've tried didn't work so you have clean function to help me base on that.

Here is what I tried:

```
orderss = Order::orderby('id', 'desc')->get(); 
$orderss = json_decode($orderss->order_data);
```

And I got this error:

> Property [order_data] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: There is a function called [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), pass your data to it

Comment: I tried no luck, if you have sample please provide maybe it works?!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: json_decode, json_encode, foreach($orders ....) and many more/ everything I could find on google :)

Comment: $orderss is a collection, not the actual row. So you need to loop through it to extract the data.

Comment: @Ibu after foreach i get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: any other idea?! these solutions are the ones I've already tried all but as you see same old problem! can't get json objects in my view :(

Comment: Note that the parent element of your json string is `29` is this normal?

Comment: @Ibu I have no idea is normal or no, I saved my cart content as json to orders table and this was the data that saved. I assume this was id of my product or cart session (not sure).

Comment: I added an answer that may work. But I hope you can redesign your json instead

Answer (score 2):

you need to loop through the variable you pass to view using something like this:

```
<div class="container">
@foreach ($orders as $order )
    {{ dd(json_decode($order->order_data, true))}}
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: array:1 [▼
  29 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 29
    "name" => "effewf"
    "price" => 24524
    "quantity" => 1
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
]

Comment: you can assign the `json_decode($order->order_data)` part to a variable and start getting the `name` as a normal array

Comment: it returns `{"29":{"id":29,"name":"effewf","price":24524,"quantity":1,"attributes":[],"conditions":[]}}`

Comment: Hi, try something like this `$data = json_decode($order->order_data,true); echo $data['29']['name']` This is to help you understand how to get the `name` our of the array, you may need to a `for` loop to get it dynamically

Comment: ok, if i do such thing `@php
                      $data = json_decode($order->order_data)
                    @endphp
                    {!! dd($data) !!}` i get this `{#869 ▼
  +"29": {#870 ▼
    +"id": 29
    +"name": "effewf"
    +"price": 24524
    +"quantity": 1
    +"attributes": []
    +"conditions": []
  }
}` but still can't get `['29']['name']`

Comment: @mafortis, you have to put `json_decode($order->order_data,true)` notice the second parameter `true`

Comment: hi, I managed to use your method here is the thing, sometimes in one order there will be several items (eg. user order 5 products at the same time) now that I get my products title and quantities it will show as `title1 title2` how can I make `,` in between or `<br>` or even better separate each orders rows.  here are some screenshots to be clear:  https://ibb.co/eLq2Bm  |  
https://ibb.co/j4YNBm

Comment: @mafortis, you can add another for loop on the `$data` , `foreach ($data as $d){echo "<span>".$d['name']."</span><br/>"}`

Comment: thanks dude I fixed that by adding `li` but somehow I cannot get sum of total quantities and price of each order.  take a look at here    https://ibb.co/bDBaWm

Comment: inside the second `for` loop, `$price += $d['price'];` then you can use `$price` for the total price of the order, same with quantity.

Comment: where this $price come from? because i get `Undefined variable: price `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163029/discussion-between-long-kim-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try sending it through php json decoder

```
 json_decode($data);
```

Comment: `orderss = Order::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        $orderss = json_decode($orderss->order_data);` returns `Property [order_data] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: Try retrieving it as an array, or simply var_dump

Comment: Already is array from my model:    `protected $casts = [
        'order_data' => 'array',
    ];`

Comment: That data looks protected, protected data can only be accessed via inheritance. See if you can set the casts to public

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the type to JSON or array in model:

```
class Order extends Model {
  protected $casts =[
    'order_data'=>'json' //'array'
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your JSON string looks like:

```
{
    "29": {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "effewf",
        "price": 24524,
        "quantity": 1,
        "attributes": [],
        "conditions": []
    }
}
```

You first have to decode it into a stdclass using json_decode, then make use of your values:

```
<div class="container">
@foreach ($orders as $jsonStr )
    {{--*/ $order = json_decode($jsonStr) /*--}}
@endforeach
</div>
```

Note that `$order` now contain your json, however you have a problem because your first element is a number. And unless you know the number ahead of time you will have a hard time retrieving it:

```
$number = "29"; // in your case but has to be parsed
$product = $order->$b;
```

now the product variable can be used as an object:

```
$product->id;
$product->price;
// etc.
```

#### Extra:

I may not recommend this, instead you should redesign your json string. But anyway here is how I retrieved the number.

```
$a = json_decode($jsonStr);
$b = get_object_vars($a);
$keys = array_keys($c);

foreach($keys as $key){
   // $key is now your key
}
```